# Handling special characters in javascript

Tags: jquery, django, javascript

In the below code:

```
var id=obj.setid({{info}});
```

I get an error saying illegal character  and `{{info}}` has the following  string:

```
"Website® is registered "
```

How do I handle this error in javascript?

Thanks..

Edit:

```
  setid looks like this
    setid: function (id)
                 {
                    var obj = $(this) ;
                     validate_id(id);
                 },
```

Comment: You don't need to use indentation *and* backticks. Use one or the other. Also, some of your non-code text has been indented, and is included in your code-block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't you need to put your string in quotes?

```
var id = obj.setid('{{info}}');
```

I can't tell from your post whether the "info" string has quotes in it already.

Answer (score 3):

```
mystring = "Website® is registered";
alert(mystring);
```

Works just fine, it has nothing to do with the value of info -- the question is what do you think you're doing with `{{info}}`?

This is wrong if obj.setid is expecting a string or an object. The correct way would be:

```
// Wants a string
obj.setid(info);

// Wants an object
obj.setid({'text':info});
```

Hard to tell without knowing what obj.setid is

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to set the id attribute of a DOM element to the value "website is registered", which is not a valid value for an id attribute.